# plotly dash: change default port

Tags: plotly-dash

Following [plotly dash getting started guide](https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started) but when trying to run `python app.py` get message:

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Seems the default address: `http://127.0.0.1:8050/` is already being used.  How can the default port be changed so I can get this to work?

Comment: generally open ports are 8124,8125,8126. You can google common open ports to make sure you don't try to take one from a major application. 8888 is good but jupyter notbooks uses that one often as well as Ambari if you are working with cloud computing stuff.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As we can see in Dash.run_server method definition, port can be passed as parameter:

```
def run_server(self,
               port=8050,
               debug=True,
               threaded=True,
               **flask_run_options):
    self.server.run(port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
```

So, if you need to use another port:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051) # or whatever you choose
```

Comment: If anyone wants to know which alternative port is available on a Windows 10 machine, type `netstat -ab` in your command line as an administrator and the ports that show the state as `LISTENING` are the ones available. More info here: https://www.alphr.com/how-to-check-which-ports-open-windows-10-pc/

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the environment variable PORT in your terminal before launching the Dash app:

https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/c77912a3183adfccfd4ef84df91eca7fa9c7d543/dash/_configs.py#L34

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Oleh's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834874/3655757), it is possible to just define a new port in the PlotlyDash `app.run()` command.

However, that does not actually solve the problem of cleaning up "hanging" or "left-over" ports opened up by PlotlyDash... A more clean solution is to identify and kill the left-over processes, thus freeing up the port. Then PlotlyDash can be re-run/started.

On Mac OSX / Linux, perform these steps:

1. Find out what is running on port 8050 (or whichever is open/occupied) by using the command in the Terminal: `lsof -i :8050`
2. Identify the PID (Process IDentifier) running on that port from the output of the `lsof` command
3. Kill the process(es), using the command `kill <PID>`

On Windows CMD, perform these steps:

1. Find out what is running on port 8050 (or whichever is open/occupied) by using the command in Windows CMD: `netstat -aon | find "8050"`
2. Identify the PID (Process IDentifier) running on that port
3. Kill the process(es), using the command `taskkill /PID <PID>`

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Julia, you can change the port by specifying the port number in the `run_server` arguments without specifying "port=". For example,

```
run_server(app, "0.0.0.0", 8000, debug = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the place of port = 8050 type your own port number

Answer (score 0):

I was running it on a Jupyter notebook, and all I had to do was go to runtime and select factory reset runtime, pip install all dependencies (like jupyter-dash), and I was good to go...